# how to rotate a point(x,y) about a fixed point

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to rotate a point (x,y) from an orientation alpha to a new point(x,y) with an orientation beta about a fixed point (centre of the circle). How to do it in ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225893/how-to-rotate-a-point(x,y)-about-a-fixed-point/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-02-05**:
I do not know if ROS has libraries for this, but Eigen might be useful as it can apply transformations to vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

General Answer, also valid for 3D:

1. Translate your point, so that your rotation axis goes through the origin of your coordinate system.
2. Rotate the transformed point around your axis.
3. Translate the origin of the coordinate system back to the old position.

In your case (P is  the point to rotate, F is the rotation point, R is the rotation matrix):

P' = F+(R*(P-F))

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0